# nVidia FX5200 Can't set resolution upper than 800x600

Tags: 12.04, resolution

When I install nVidia drivers from terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

... and I reboot, I get the max. resolution 800x600.
I added new mode successfully with `xrandr`, but my display is 480p.
My display is connected to my PC with HDMI and in Windows I was have VGA resolution on HDMI but after I installed in Ubuntu the drivers, the resolution is 480p.How to fix that?
And can I change the 420p to 720p or 1080i ? Because my display have option "HDMI Full PC mode" which is good because I can see my display fully, but the Full PC mode is not supported for 480p.

Ubuntu: 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FX5200 is 9 years old now - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_FX_Series#Hardware_refreshes_and_diversification). It's not supported by the Nvidia current driver anymore. You need the 173.x branch of the driver. (read [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.36-driver.html)). Install it using the `nvidia-173-updates` package instead of `current`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run nvidia-settings to change the resolution.  If you don't have the correct resolutions selectable in Xserver_Display_Configuration check the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf for incorrect Vertrefresh and Horizsync settings and delete those lines.